# Remove white shadow on tabbar

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uitabbar

I am using customized `UITabbar` in my app. When a tab is selected `tabbaritem` icon is shown with a white shadow. Is there any way to remove this? i have tried a lot but i did not get any solution. the screen shot is below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your code :

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Hope it helps you.